# store history of user login pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have been recently using python and pyqt for UI design. currently I am creating a popup screen where the user will select their name click login to proceed further to use any application. My aim is to have a history of user login stored as a collection (perhaps a list) for further mainpulation. Sharing basic code related to popup screen.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.contributors=['','A','B','C']
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        self.nameLabel=QLabel(self)
        self.nameLabel.setText("Select Your name")
        self.nameLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.cb=QComboBox(self)
        self.cb.setGeometry(QRect(40,40,491, 31))
        self.cb.setObjectName(("comboBox"))
        self.cb.addItems(self.contributors)
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.getEditor)
        self.buttonLogin = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.nameLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
        self.resize(600,150)    
        self.exec_()

    def getEditor(self):
        text=str(self.cb.currentText()) 
        return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login=Login()
```

currently I am storing a text file with all the names selected from the combo box and manipulating it. Is there a cleaner way to get a list of users who used the tool? I am trying to avoid creating an extra text file.

Any help would be welcome. I was not able to get relevant answer through search. If this query has been answered, please direct me to the link.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a file or a database to store that data.

Comment: @eyllanesc- I agree that would work. I already am using an approach similar to what you have mentioned. Storing the value in a external file and then manipulating the data. I hope I have understood the comment correctly.

Comment: I am curious if we can create a list of all users without using an external file. Say if 'A' logs in list would have [ 'A']. If 'B' logs in the new list would be [ 'A','B'] etc.

Comment: The programs are loaded into the RAM, and after closing it is erased from memory, so it is impossible, only the hard drive saves the data permanently. that's why external files are used that are saved on the hard drive.

Comment: @eyllanesc- Thanks for the insight.

Comment: one more query. Is this the common way of handling requests for manipulating user list etc?

Comment: explain better, it means what is the most usual way to save a history, for those cases I personally use a database, sqlite is perfect for these cases.

Comment: This is quite a broad question and answers are likely to be opinion based (which makes it out of scope for stack overflow). I would suggest posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AnoopAM. If you use [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#details), Qt will do most of the work for you, so there's no need to mess around with text files and such like.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a file in the "a+" method means, if a file with the specified name exists, append text to him, if that certain file doesn't exist create one with that name.

```
class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        self.contributors=['','A','B','C']
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)

        ...

        self.buttonLogin = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.user_entered)

        ...

    def user_entered(self):
        text = str(self.cb.currentText())
        with open("my log file", "a+") as file:  # wirting user name into a file
            file.write(text + "\n")
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login=Login()
    login.show()
    app.exec_()  # delete the exec_() call in your window __init__
```

Comment: thanks for the update. This is similar to approach I am using. All comments and answers point to either external database or QSettings. I will try these alternatives to check it suitability.

Comment: @AnoopAM yes, database is far better, but I would suggest to learn python basics first, before you approach DBs.